# Power BI - Automatically update CSV data source

Tags: csv, powerbi, updates, powerbi-desktop

I am quite a newbie on Power BI so I am still trying to understand some concepts. I did my PBI dashboard with some CSV as data sources. Then, I tried to add some informations on my CSV but when I go back to PBI, the CSV are not modified.

So, how do I get my data sources to update automatically?

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: Did u deploy the report or u r referring to Desktop app ?

Comment: @Roshan I am still on the Desktop app and the csv is on my computer

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the report ?

Comment: Yes, but I found the answer. I did some operations on the column in Power Query so I needed to correct that after refreshing.